# SSDT Incorrect syntax near <password> expecting ID or Quoted ID

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-data-tools

This script runs fine in SSMS but in my SQL Server Data Tools data project in Visual studio it gives me an error. Script:

```
create user [myUsername] with password = 'myPassword'
```

Error:

```
SQL 80001 : Incorrect Syntax near "myPassword". Expecting ID, or Quoted ID
```

Comment: Users don't have passwords; logins have passwords. That's probably your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think it should be Login instead user

```
create LOGIN [myUsername] with password='myPassword'
```

OR if login exists

```
CREATE USER [myUsername] FOR LOGIN sa WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
```

Comment: yeah that worked, thanks. it's weird that 'user' works in SSMS though.